# how to smart update a value based on heavy calculation every n seconds (performance)

Tags: python, django, performance, asynchronous

In django we have a `Task` model that contains a 'progress' Float field. This progress float field is calculated based on some calculation of related outputs (`Output` model). We use a trigger (using django signals (on save of the `Output`) that recalculate the progress Float field each time the value of the outputs changes.

This does not scale well and when bulk updating the `Output` the progress re-calculation is triggered many times (blocking, not async) which is only needed at the end of the bulk update sequence.

I am looking for performance improvements and and came up with the following solution options

1. save a 'dirty' flag in the `Task` object and let a async runner (on a beat) scan for these dirty flags and recalculate the property when needed, or
2. only update the progress if it was updated > n seconds ago (a TTL), or
3. Delay (put in async queue) by n seconds and if in the meantime another progress recalculation task is put in the queue, delete the original one.

I am looking for a proper implementation pattern that does not recalculate the progress every trigger, but maximum every n seconds, and after n seconds I do have a consistent state (correctly calculated progress).